# How to access element from code in WPF with multiple XAML files

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two xaml files.
The main.xaml file and a secondary file called test.xaml

In the main.xaml file I use (with a frame) the test.xaml file.

```
<Frame x:Name="test" Source="test.xaml"/>
```

All elements have names using the x:names tag.
How do I programatically access the elements from the test.xaml from my main.xaml code behind file?

Zjeriet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I programatically access the elements

From your main page code behind cast the `source` element to the class instance name which test.xaml is based off of and access it in codebehind appropriately.

```
var myPage = test.Source as {InsertClassNameHere};
```

Comment: I've added 
'x:Class="Skeiron.TestPage"' 
to the test.xaml page

And added 
'var myPage = NMSRing.Source as {Skeiron.TestPage};' 
to my code of my main page.

I receive a type expected error.

Comment: @Zjerre you mean it can't find  the class `Skeiron.TestPage`?

Comment: Yes looks like it. 
I don't have a code behind file for the test.xaml page. Is that a problem.
test.xaml is in the same namespace though

Comment: @Zjerre No codefile means that the xaml for that page is just parsed into the current page and ultimately displayed. The only way to access the elements would be to traverse the UI tree at runtime. I recommend an alternate of putting the xaml into a user control. That will give you the access you want and a code behind file.